# Database/Object Mapping

Tags: c#, database, linq-to-sql, object

This is a beginner question, but it's been frustrating me...
I am using C#, by the way.

I'd like to make a few classes, each with their own properties and methods.  I would also like to have a database to store certain instances of these classes in case I would ever need to look at them again.  So, for example...

```
class Polygon
{
    String name;
    Double perimiter;
    int numSides;
    public Double GetArea()
    {
        // ...
    }
}

class Circle
{
    String name;
    Double radius;
    public void PrintName()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Say I've got these classes.  I also want a database that has the TABLES "Polygon" and "Circle" with the COLUMNS "name" "perimeter" "radius" etc.  And I want an easy way to save a class instance into the database, or pull a class instance out of the database.

I have previously been using MS Access for my database stuff, which I don't mind using, but I would prefer if nothing other than .NET need to be installed.

I've been researching online a bit, but I wanted to get some opinions on here.  I have looked at Linq-to-Sql, but it seems you need Sql-Server.  Is this true?  If so, I'd really rather not use it because I don't want to have to have it installed everywhere.

Anway, I'm just fishing for some ideas/insights/suggestions/etc. so please help me out if you can.

Thanks.

Comment: Any of these answers help you out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LINQ2SQL` is ideal for 1 to 1 object relational mappings. That is, where the properties of the object are persisted as columns in a database. Which appears to be your situation.

The native provider for `LINQ2SQL` is naturally for `SQL Server` but there are now 3rd party providers for `Oracle`, `MySql` and `PostGreSQL`.

Using `LINQ2SQL` with `SQL Server` means you just need an instance of the database in a location addressable by your program. `SQL Server` itself will only need to be installed at that location.

Answer (score 2):

[Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) with [SQL Server Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Database/) would suit your needs.  EF may be overkill, but SQLServer Express can easily be installed by your application installer on the local machine and provides a much richer DB feature set than access does.

You may also want to look at [SQLLite](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/), which is an embedded database which requires no installation, just the distribution of a few more libraries.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using SQL CE 4.0 (public beta 2) and EF code first (CTP 5)

EF: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=35adb688-f8a7-4d28-86b1-b6235385389d

SQL CE: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=d9d933e7-9376-445e-8217-0c1e102a380e

Don't let the beta state scare you, both products are already very stable and if it's for a hobby project, or just learning, I wouldn't hesitate.

Creating/quering a database can be as simple as

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Database;
using System.Linq;

namespace EFCodeFirst
{
    public class Polygon
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public Double Perimiter { get; set; }
    }

    public class Circle
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public Double Radius { get; set; }
    }

    public class ShapeDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Polygon> Polygons { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Circle> Circles { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DbDatabase.SetInitializer(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<BookDbContext>());

            using(var context = new ShapeDbContext())
            {
                // creating a new object
                context.Polygons.Add(new Polygon { Name = "P1", Perimiter = 3 });
                context.Polygons.Add(new Polygon { Name = "P2", Perimiter = 2 });

                context.SaveChanges();
            }

            using(var context = new ShapeDbContext())
            {
                // creating a new object
                var polygons = context.Polygons.Where(o => o.Perimiter < 3);

                Console.WriteLine(polygons.Count());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the connection string you need to add to app.config for it to work

<connectionStrings>
  <add name="ShapeDbContext" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Database.sdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
</connectionStrings>

One major drawback is that you cannot update an existing database - you'll have to do it manually - however that should be fixed with the final release of EF Code First... somewhere in january hopefully...
Some majar plusses: don't need much code for simple stuff, you can still digg deep, Linq is fun, EF Code First is fun... Give it a try!

Answer (score 1):

I've never used it myself, but I know that NHibernate does what you are asking: http://www.nhibernate.com/

Answer (score 1):

no its not necessory that u shud have sql server for linq to sql,u can also use add>>newItem>>localdatabse in ur project.and u can use linq to sql with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can always serialize the objects to xml files, then deserialize them when you want to get them back.

I know you said you want a database, but I'm not sure how you can have a database without installing one.